# Log in as anonymous user ASMACK XMPP ANDROID

Tags: java, android, xmpp, asmack

How can I log into my server using anonymous user with ASMACK library for XMPP in android?

I am using `OpenFire` server

Right now I am getting my self logged in using this code:

```
String host = "web.xyz.com"; //getText(R.id.host);
String port = "5222";  //getText(R.id.port);
String service = "web.xyz.com";//getText(R.id.service);
String username = Register.username; //getText(R.id.userid);
String password = Register.pass; //getText(R.id.password);

ServiceProvider.Register_Providers(ProviderManager.getInstance());
// Create a connection
connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(host, Integer.parseInt(port),service);
connection = new XMPPConnection("host");

try {
    connection.connect();
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Connected to " + connection.getHost());
} catch (XMPPException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to connect to " + ex.getMessage());
    Register.setConnection(null);
}
try {
    connection.login(username, password);
    Log.i("XMPPClient", "Logged in as " + connection.getUser());

    // Set the status to available
    Presence presence = new Presence(Presence.Type.available);
    connection.sendPacket(presence);
    Register.setConnection(connection);
} catch (XMPPException ex) {
    Log.e("XMPPClient", "[SettingsDialog] Failed to log in as " + username);
    Register.setConnection(null);
}
```

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: what do you use ? openfire ? ejabberd ?

Comment: Have you configured local server and configure user credential? server like ejjaberd ,quickblox etc.

Comment: yes i am using openfire server. and i can log in with a user name and password that has already been registered in the server. but i cannot log in anonymously

Comment: see, xmpp/openfire provide us this facility to log in anonymously with the server. i want to log in my self anonymously

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to login [anonymously](http://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0175.html), you must enable anonymous connections at the server, and you does not need to provide username and password, just use [connection.loginAnonymously()](http://www.igniterealtime.org/builds/smack/docs/latest/javadoc/org/jivesoftware/smack/XMPPConnection.html#loginAnonymously%28%29) instead of `login()`